R is not rendering to pdf tlmgr
i have a Rmarkdown document  that contains a data frame and a plot in the same chunck.
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: "2024-04-23"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstats)
library(purrr)

likert_levels <- c(
  "Strongly disagree",
  "Disagree",
  "Neither agree nor disagree",
  "Agree",
  "Strongly agree"
)

df <-
  tibble(
    "there is an argument sort_prop_include_center that could be set up to TRUE in order to include half of the centered level when sorting data" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE),
    "Similarly, the argument totals_include_center allows you to include half of the centered level into the left and the right totals" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = 5:1),
    "Here is one possible option which uses reorder and an ifelse to reorder the variable mapped on y using the counts (aka the sum) of Strictly disagree " = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = 1:5),
    "and disagree answers. Under the hood ggstats::gglikert reshape the data to long where the question id's are stored in a column named .question and the answers in a column named .answer:" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = 1:5),
    "They used sampling data and create a data frame called df. I am using the same as given in the link.(the df not the df_dk). Ok, if i run in R the following code :" = sample(c(likert_levels, NA), 150, replace = TRUE),
    "proportion of answers higher than the centered level. I want the plot to be sorted according to very left proportions that are the combination (sum) of the two lower levels. (i.e Respectively the percentages on the very right in the sum of the two lower categories. )" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0))
  ) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ factor(.x, levels = likert_levels)))

# function to save retyping common arguments
anno <- partial(annotate, "text", x = -1, angle = 90, size = 5, fontface = "bold")

gglikert(df) +
  aes(y = reorder(.question,
                  ifelse(
                    .answer %in% c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree"),
                    1, 0
                  ),
                  FUN = sum, decreasing = TRUE
  )) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(1.5, 5.5), linetype = "dashed", colour = "grey20") +
  anno(y = 1, label = "warning\nzone", color = "#A6611A") +
  anno(y = 3.5, label = "so-so", color = "black") +
  anno(y = 6, label = "no warning\nzone", color = "#018571") +
  labs(y = NULL)



 I tried to render it to pdf but i always receive the same error : 

|.....................                               |  40% [setup]
processing file: test-pdf.Rmd
|..........................................          |  80% [unnamed-chunk-1]This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator.
Error in if (year < 2023 && warn) ...:
! missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Backtrace:

rmarkdown::render(...)
knitr (local) <fn>(...)
knitr::plot_crop(f)
knitr:::has_utility("pdfcrop")
knitr:::has_crop_tools()

Quitting from lines  at lines 13-54 [unnamed-chunk-1] (test-pdf.Rmd)
Warning message:
In system2("tlmgr", args, ...) :
running command '"tlmgr" --version' had status 1
Execution halted



what is wrong here? I am using :

getRversion()
[1] ‘4.3.3’
with tinytex and Miktex
on windows 11. I tried to install, reinstall and update several times tinytex Miktex and Rstudio.But i am always receiving the same error.Why ?   


Works fine for me, no  errors (only title and date though). Looks like insufficient user rights or firewall issues.

@jay.sf i there a way to find where the code hits the error ?

maybe in the tex source; in RStudio, click on the cogwheel right from the Knit button > Advanced > check Keep. Then examine the .tex file produced.

where i can find this tex file ?

same folder of .Rmd

@jay.sf ok i saw it inside the test-pdf.files folder there is a pdf with the plot.Only that

Actually meant the .log file, should end .log with same prefix as your .Rmd file

@jay.sf no log file on this folder (direction where the .rmd exists)

have you cogwheel (right from the Knit button) > Output options > Advanced > checked Keep? Or try  add keep_tex: true one line below pdf_document:, and two chars extra indented.
